# 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement' - when media src has delay

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, html5-video, mobile-safari

When trying to trigger playback on video elements on chrome and safari, i got the following message:

```
Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

see a example: https://jsfiddle.net/joshrezende/4dL1boc9/10/

have read a lot on the web but no find an solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this on mobile browsers? Mobile browsers require a user gesture for play().

Comment: but I did a test and I managed to play just using the api, see: https://jsfiddle.net/joshrezende/4dL1boc9/12/

Comment: I apologize if I am being dense, Josh. Are you getting the error in Chrome on desktop / Chrome on Android?

The example seems to work fine for me on Chrome on desktop.

Comment: No problem, but I have this error feedback when using browsers mobile, I know it's a feature, but the question and realized that if the url to the file already is been placed it works, if you can do the test with the player in both urls, you will notice that with having setTimeout fires error